# linux permissions does not update rapidly

Tags: linux, permissions, grouping, auto-update

i am using linux. a want a group only can access to a folder. i create a group and set group of that folder to new created folder. ( by `chgrp` command ). and change the access to folder by `chmod 070`( only group can read-write-execute). in last, i add my user to new created folder. in this case i must can change directory to that folder, because i am a member of that group.
i can not access to that file but if i log-out from system and login again, i can use that folder. why this problem occurs? i must run which command to update user groups?

Answer (score 2):

It's because things like which groups a user belongs to are read only on login. Once a user has logged in, you can change the users groups all you want, but it will not be reloaded automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
exec su -l $USER
```

I think it makes you re authenticate but should work

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/74934/refresh-supplementary-group-memberships-without-logging-in-again